# Build private chats in Firebase and Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am building an app with Firebase that requires private messaging between users.
What I need is to build single chats for 1-1 chats, storing messages in Firestore.

**My idea:** I guess the best way is to build a single collection for each chat, with the right security rules. Let's say an user with tokenID 1234 wants to talk with user with tokenID 1111, a new collection called 1234_1111 will be created (if not existing), and the security will allow only these two users to read and write.

**My question:** Is it the right way? And how to do that in Javascript? I'm not sure how to define security rules directly in the JS code, neither how to create a collection with the two users ID.

Comment: When I talk about security rules, Im not talking about privacy at all... I just want to allow read and write for a given documents to specific users. Why are you talking about PGP encryption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security Rules are not defined in your JavaScript code, they are [defined separately](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started). What you suggest would be a reasonable approach to take although I'd use a subcollection for it, and a simplified version of your security rules might look something like:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /dms/{idPair}/messages/{msgId} {
      allow read, write: if 
        idPair.split('_')[0] == request.auth.uid ||
        idPair.split('_')[1] == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your JS code you could do something along the lines of:

```
// generate idPair
function dmCollection(uid) {
  const idPair = [firebase.auth().currentUser.uid, toUid].join('_').sort();
  return firebase.firestore().collection('dms').doc(idPair).collection('messages');
}

// send a DM
function sendDM(toUid, messageText) {
  return dmCollection(toUid).add({
    from: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
    text: messageText,
    sent: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
  });
}

// retrieve DMs
function messagesWith(uid) {
  return dmCollection(uid).orderBy('sent', 'desc').get();
}
```

Note that the `idPair` is constructed by joining a sorted pair of UIDs so that it will be stable no matter which user sends.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I will try it. So, for sure, you cannot edit the security rules directly from the code?

Comment: You can [use the Firebase CLI to deploy rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/manage-deploy) from a local `.rules` file, but the rules language is not JavaScript and won't be part of your JS code.

Comment: Kindly edit `dmCollection` param to `toUid`, thanks for the answer though